# playing mp3 file in the background of the python application (windows OS)

Tags: python, python-turtle, playsound

I'm building a simple space war game using python turtle.
I want to play a laser sound every time I fire a missile, so I'm using the command:
playsound("laser.mp3)
the problem is that my game pause until the end of the sound. how do I make the sound play in the background?
I know that for Mac system the command is os.system("afplay laser.mp3&"). What should be the command for Windows?

I try to play the mp3 file in the background of the game but the games keep pausing till the end of the mp3 file

Comment: Please share your current code as a [mcve]. Rather than using an OS-specific subprocess call to a third party utility, I would use a Python sound library. Or use Pygame, since it's more suited for the use case of playing sounds in a game.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cmd commands using `os` module:

```
os.system("start cmd /c {command here}")     # Launches in new command prompt, closes when done
```

in your case you can use something like:

```
import os
os.system("start cmd /C \"afplay laser.mp3\"")
```